# PHP elseif statement usage for form validation and insert to db

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to make my form validation and db insert script work but am facing problems again. I am using an elseif statement to do:

1. Check if the form was actually submitted by the user clicking the submit button and all data fields completed, if not warn and redirect back to the form page (this is the only part that seems to be working)
2. If the form has been completed fully and submit button clicked then connect to mysql server and select db or die and display error message
3. If there is a connection to the database then insert the form data to the table

I can prevent the entry of empty fields but that is all,everything else seems to break. I cannot seem to figure out why. `tail -f /var/log/apache2/error.log` displays nothing. Perhaps I have over complicated things. I have been using this site as a reference and http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_if_else.asp for elseif syntax, newbie still screwing things up.

Here is the code:

```
<?php
//Form fields passed to variables
$manu = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputManu']);
$model = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputModel']);
$desc = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputDesc']);

//Connect to database using $conn
include ('connection.php');

//Insert record into table 
$sql = "INSERT INTO gear (`id`,`manu`,`model`,`desc`)
      VALUES (NULL,'$manu','$model','$desc')";

//Check for empty fields
if ($_POST['submit']) 
{   
   foreach($_POST as $val) 
{
      if(trim($val) == '' || empty($val))
        {
        die();
      echo "Please complete all form fields!";
      echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../add.php'>"; 
      //header("Location: ../add.php?error=empty_fields");
        }
    }
}
elseif (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
{
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
}
else
{
  //echo "1 record added";
  echo "Success, You added the ".$manu." ".$model."";
  echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../index.php'>";
}   
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: 1) Stop using W3Schools. It's a terrible resource. See http://w3fools.com for why. 2) Stop using `mysql_*` functions *anywhere* in your code. They're deprecated -- switch to MySQLi or PDO and use prepared statements to guard against SQL injection vulnerabilities.

Comment: @AmalMurali OP already using mysqli_*

Comment: @Mrcoder: Look at the first few lines of code.

Comment: @AmalMurali aah my bad i saw the last few lines. :)

Comment: I would start with doing some basic debugging. do some echoes to see where your program goes. For instance, you have at some point an 'empty' `die();`, with some echoes behind that. The die will not show an error in your log I think anyway, but you won't get any output like this whatsoever. So echo some "I'm here" lines, var_dump the various steps etc, and just look at what your code is doing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to move the query execution part inside the first if.your full code should look like this:

```
<?php
 //Connect to database using $conn
include ('connection.php');
//Form fields passed to variables
$manu = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputManu']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputModel']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($_POST['inputDesc']);



//Insert record into table 
$sql = "INSERT INTO gear (`id`,`manu`,`model`,`desc`)
      VALUES (NULL,'$manu','$model','$desc')";

//Check for empty fields
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{   
   foreach($_POST as $val) 
    {
      if(trim($val) == '' || empty($val))
        {
        die();
      echo "Please complete all form fields!";
      echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../add.php'>"; 
      //header("Location: ../add.php?error=empty_fields");
        }
    }

     if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
     {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
     }
     else
     {
       //echo "1 record added";
         echo "Success, You added the ".$manu." ".$model."";
         echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../index.php'>";
     }   
}
else
{
echo "some error";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: You can't use `mysqli_real_escape_string` without a connection. Not that you need to, since you chose to use mysqli, you should be using prepared statements anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions and help however this code will not work now. It is inserting empty rows even when fields are full and the check for empty fields no longer works either. I am trying to troubleshoot this, Could the `mysqli_real_escape_string` be the problem, I do not understand what Madara was saying about the use of that.

Comment: @user3146788: If this isn't the correct solution, why did you mark it as correct? (With the green "Accept" tickmark)?

Comment: It was the solution that actually provided code suggestions and some direction. You posted helpful information but confused me even more with suggestions of prepared statements, which as a beginner I know nothing about. I will post the revised code with the proper use of the `mysqli_real_escape_string`.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha corrected my answer.i overlooked mysql_real_escape_string.thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code that works but I am sure there are some more refinements that could be made:

```
<?php
//Connect to database using $conn
include ('connection.php');

//Form fields passed to variables
$manu = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['inputManu']);
$model = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['inputModel']);
$desc = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['inputDesc']);

//Insert record into table 
$sql = "INSERT INTO gear (`id`,`manu`,`model`,`desc`)
      VALUES (NULL,'$manu','$model','$desc')";

//Check for empty fields
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{   
   foreach($_POST as $val) 
    {
      if(trim($val) == '' || empty($val))
        {
//        echo "Please complete all form fields!";
        echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../add.php'>"; 
          die('Error: Please complete all form fields!' . mysqli_error());
        }
    }

     if (!mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
     {
     die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
     }
     else
     {
       //echo "1 record added";
         echo "Success, You added the ".$manu." ".$model."";
         echo "<meta http-equiv='Refresh' content='3; URL=../index.php'>";
     }   
}
else
{
echo "some error";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```